# How to output text from lists of variable sizes using printf?

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to automate some output using [printf](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/de/maxima_73.html#printf) but I'm struggling to find a way to pass to it the list of arguments `expr_1, ..., expr_n` in

```
printf (dest, string, expr_1, ..., expr_n)
```

I thought of using something like Javascript's `spread` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript) but I'm not even sure I should need it.

For instace, say I have a list of strings to be output

```
a:["foo","bar","foobar"];
```

a string of appropriate format descriptors, say

```
s: "~a ~a ~a ~%";
```

and an output stream, say `os`. How can I invoke `printf` using these things in such a way that the result will be the same as writing

```
printf(os,s,a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

Then I could generalize it to output lists of variable size.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I just learned about `apply` and, using the conditions I posed in my OP, the following seems to work wonderfully:

```
apply(printf,append([os,s],a));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maxima `printf` implements most or maybe all of the formatting operators from Common Lisp FORMAT, which are quite extensive; see: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm See also `? printf` in Maxima to get an abbreviated list of formatting operators.

In particular for a list you can do something like:

```
printf (os, "my list: ~{~a~^, ~}~%", a);
```

to get the elements of `a` separated by `,`. Here `"~{...~}"` tells printf to expect a list, and `~a` is how to format each element, `~^` means omit the inter-element stuff after the last element, and `,` means put that between elements. Of course `,` could be anything.

There are many variations on that; if that's not what you're looking for, maybe I can help you find it.

Comment: This is excelent! Thank you.